# Erro quando compilo um projecto no Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Tenho um projecto que tava a funcionar normalmente, mas ontem tive que instalar o Windows no meu computador. E hoje abro o projecto e quando tento compilar, recebo essa mensagem:

> Error:(1, 1) error: illegal character: '\ufeff'
>   Error:(1, 10) error: class, interface, or enum expected
>   Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
>   Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
>   :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED

Comment: Já tentou dar um clean no project? Vai em **Build/Clean Project**, deve resolver.

Comment: O clean não resulta, mas já consegui. É que antes de instalar o novo sistema, tava a usar o Gradle 2.1.3 e o setup do Android Studio que tenho tem o Gradle 2.1.2, então tive que actualizar.